# ASP .NET Core 2 свойство навигации

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Создал два класса со связью один к одному

```
public class Example
{ 
    // id и т.д.

    [ForeignKey("CategoryFacetItem")]
    [Display(Name = "Категория")]
    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual FacetItem CategoryFacetItem{ get; set; }
}

public class FacetItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int FacetId { get; set; }
    public Facet Facet { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

При создании миграции `Add-Migration` и генерации базы данных `Update-Database` все работает хорошо, внешний ключ добавляется корректно.

Но при попытке перейти по связи `CategoryFacetItem.Name` ничего нет, 
`CategoryFacetItem` - null

В контроллере использую Bind

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("CategoryId,CategoryFacetItem")] Parcel parcel)
```

Comment: Стало быть в БД запись есть и внешними ключами соединены? Если так, то покажите каким образом Вы производите выборку из БД? И насколько я понимаю это не относится к ASP .Net...

Answer (score 0):

Предположительно проблема в том, что свойство `CategoryFacetItem` в модели является навигационным свойством Entity Framework. Оно будет содержать `null`, до тех пор, пока вы явно не укажете при выборке сущности `Example` из БД, что данный связанный объект необходимо загрузить. В вашем методе, который получает сущности `Example` из базы, нужно сделать примерно следущее:

```
 var examples = _context.Examples
        .Include(example => example.CategoryFacetItem)
        .ToList();
```

Также, начиная с версии EF Core 2.1 доступна "ленивая загрузка" связанных данных - EF загрузит значение свойства при первом обращении к нему. Пример включения ленивой загрузки приведен в этом сообщении https://stackoverflow.com/a/52027987/4624763 . Надеюсь, это поможет.